# Write text along a curve in Java

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I was wondering if it were possible to fit text along the curve of a circle. It would be great if there were a way to accomplish this in Java2D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Draw text along a curve](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtextalongacurve.htm) with just awt and swing libraries.