# Java - Draw text around edge of circle, at both top and bottom

Tags: java, image, image-processing, graphics

I am looking to draw outlined text around the radius of a circle, both at the top and the bottom, with both sections of text facing the correct way.

[How to draw an outline around text in AWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016001/how-to-draw-an-outline-around-text-in-awt) and [Write text along a curve in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094844/write-text-along-a-curve-in-java) have helped me to create code (below) that will draw text character-by-character, where each character is rotated independantly (with a few minor graphical glitches that will be the subject of a different question).

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CreateTextStackOverflow {
    private static final int EDGE_GAP = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(364,364,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bi.getGraphics();

        Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,48);

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int imageWidth = bi.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = bi.getHeight();
        int centerX = imageWidth/2;
        int centerY = imageHeight/2;
        int radius = Math.min(centerX,centerY)-EDGE_GAP-((int)Math.ceil(fm.getMaxCharBounds(g).getHeight()/2.0));

        drawOutlinedTextAroundCircle(g,"TOP TEXT",0,false,imageWidth,imageHeight,radius,centerX,centerY,font,Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
        drawOutlinedTextAroundCircle(g,"BOTTOM TEXT",0,true,imageWidth,imageHeight,radius,centerX,centerY,font,Color.RED,Color.WHITE);

        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("test.png"));
    }

    private static void drawOutlinedTextAroundCircle(Graphics2D g, String text, int textCenterAngleDegrees, boolean atBottom, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int radius, int centerX, int centerY, Font font, Color outlineColour, Color innerColour) {
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        char[] characters = text.toCharArray();
        int characterCount = characters.length;
        int spaceCharacterWidth = fm.charWidth('n');
        boolean[] spaces = new boolean[characterCount];
        int[] characterWidths = new int[characterCount+1];
        characterWidths[characterCount] = 0;
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            char character = characters[index];
            spaces[index] = character == ' ' || Character.isSpaceChar(character);
            characterWidths[index] = spaces[index]?spaceCharacterWidth:fm.charWidth(character);
        }
        double currentAngle = 0;
        double[] characterAngles = new double[characterCount];
        int leading = fm.getLeading();
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            characterAngles[index] = currentAngle;
            currentAngle += Math.sin(((characterWidths[index]/2.0) + leading + (characterWidths[index+1]/2.0)) / (double)radius);
        }
        double adjustment = (textCenterAngleDegrees * Math.PI / 180) - ((characterAngles[characterCount-1] - characterAngles[0]) / 2.0);
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            characterAngles[index] += adjustment;
        }
        AffineTransform flipTransform = new AffineTransform();
        if (atBottom) {
            flipTransform.scale(1,-1);
            flipTransform.translate(0,-imageHeight);
        }
        AffineTransform translateTransform = new AffineTransform(flipTransform);
        translateTransform.translate(centerX, centerY);
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            if (!spaces[index]) {
                AffineTransform rotateTransform = new AffineTransform(translateTransform);
                rotateTransform.rotate(characterAngles[index], 0.0, 0.0);
                float x = (float)(-(characterWidths[index]/2.0));
                float y = (float)(-radius);
                FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
                String str = new String(characters,index,1);
                GlyphVector glyphVector = font.createGlyphVector(frc, str);
                Rectangle2D box = glyphVector.getVisualBounds();
                g.setTransform(rotateTransform);
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                Shape shape = glyphVector.getOutline((float)(x - box.getX()), (float)(y - box.getY()));
                g.setColor(innerColour);
                g.fill(shape);
                g.setColor(outlineColour);
                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
                g.draw(shape);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(which produces)

[image: Output of code]

This has the problem where the text at the bottom is not the correct way around.

I have made several attempts at using different affine transforms to change each character as it is drawn, but to no avail.

What I am aiming for is a solution where 0 degrees results in text centered at the top/bottom of the circle, and increasing the number of degrees moves the text further to the right, as shown in this diagram mocked up in GIMP:

[image: Diagram]

What is the correct way to draw text in this manner?

Comment: Instead of directly working on transformations you can use `#rotate()` and `#scale()` (`-1` argument gives you mirrored view in given axis)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Comment: @kzrycheck Thanks. I hadn't realised this was possible. However using AffineTransforms allows me define a transform for everything and a transform per character, without having to undo the transform for each character before starting the next. Plus the ability to undo becomes more important in the solution I am about to post.

Comment: You can also copy the graphics2d object through `create()` method to have fully isolated transformations eg. Per method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from scratch using the code that I had written and post to the original question as a base, and also countless sheets of paper, I worked out for this to work:

If text is at the bottom, and increasing angles moves the text to the left *(different from what was originally asked)*

Do sequentially:

- Put the characters in reverse order
- Rotate the image 180 degrees
- Flip each glyph horizontally and vertically

If text is at the bottom, and increasing angles moves the text to the right

Either:

- Do the above, but negate the angle first
- Do sequentially:

  - Flip the entire image horizontally
  - Rotate the image 180 degrees
  - Flip each glyph vertically

The below solution implements this (using the left option). It also separates the logic of text styling from text positioning:

```
package uk.co.scottdennison.java.testbed;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import uk.co.scottdennison.java.testbed.TextUtilities.CircularTextPosition;
import uk.co.scottdennison.java.testbed.TextUtilities.GlyphDrawer;

import static uk.co.scottdennison.java.testbed.TextUtilities.CircularTextPosition.BASELINE_ON_CIRCLE;
import static uk.co.scottdennison.java.testbed.TextUtilities.CircularTextPosition.INSIDE_CIRCLE;
import static uk.co.scottdennison.java.testbed.TextUtilities.CircularTextPosition.OUTSIDE_CIRCLE;

public class CreateText4 {
    private static final int IMAGE_SIZE = 364;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOUR = new Color(242,247,254);
    private static final Font FONT = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,48);
    private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(1f);
    private static final Color UPPER_TEXT_FILL_COLOUR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Color UPPER_TEXT_OUTLINE_COLOUR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color LOWER_TEXT_FILL_COLOUR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Color LOWER_TEXT_OUTLINE_COLOUR = Color.BLUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (CircularTextPosition textPosition : CircularTextPosition.values()) {
            for (int squash=0; squash<=1; squash++) {
                for (int angle=0; angle<360; angle+=15) {
                    int edgeGap = 0;
                    switch (textPosition) { // For the demo, the edge gaps need to be different, but the enum in TextUtilities could be in a completely separate library so should have no knowledge of this.
                        case INSIDE_CIRCLE:
                            edgeGap = 10;
                            break;
                        case BASELINE_ON_CIRCLE:
                            edgeGap = 40;
                            break;
                        case OUTSIDE_CIRCLE:
                            edgeGap = 70;
                            break;
                    }
                    draw(angle,edgeGap,squash==1,textPosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void draw(int angle, int edgeGap, boolean squash, CircularTextPosition circularTextPosition) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("angle=" + angle + " / squash=" + squash + " / circularTextPosition=" + circularTextPosition);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bi.getGraphics();

        double center = IMAGE_SIZE/2.0;
        double radius = center-edgeGap;
        int flooredCenter = (int)Math.floor(center);
        int ceiledCenter = (int)Math.ceil(center);

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOUR);
        g.fillRect(-1,-1,IMAGE_SIZE+2,IMAGE_SIZE+2);

        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE);
        g.drawLine(flooredCenter, 0, flooredCenter, IMAGE_SIZE);
        if (flooredCenter != ceiledCenter) {
            g.drawLine(flooredCenter-1, 0, flooredCenter-1, IMAGE_SIZE);
        }
        g.drawLine(IMAGE_SIZE, 0, 0, IMAGE_SIZE);
        g.drawLine(0, flooredCenter, IMAGE_SIZE, flooredCenter);
        if (flooredCenter != ceiledCenter) {
            g.drawLine(0, flooredCenter-1, IMAGE_SIZE, flooredCenter-1);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval((int)(center-radius),(int)(center-radius),(int)(radius+radius-1),(int)(radius+radius-1));

        TextUtilities.drawTextAroundCircle(g,"Top y Text"   ,angle,squash,circularTextPosition,false,radius,center,center,FONT,new OutlinedFilledGlyphDrawer(UPPER_TEXT_FILL_COLOUR,UPPER_TEXT_OUTLINE_COLOUR,STROKE));
        TextUtilities.drawTextAroundCircle(g,"Bottom y Text",angle,squash,circularTextPosition,true ,radius,center,center,FONT,new OutlinedFilledGlyphDrawer(LOWER_TEXT_FILL_COLOUR,LOWER_TEXT_OUTLINE_COLOUR,STROKE));

        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(String.format("test_%s_%s_%03d.png", circularTextPosition.name().toLowerCase().replace("_","-"),squash?"squashed":"normal",angle)));
    }

    public static class OutlinedFilledGlyphDrawer implements GlyphDrawer {
        private Color oldGraphicsStateColor;
        private Stroke oldGraphicsStateStroke;
        private final Color fillColour;
        private final Color outlineColour;
        private final Stroke stroke;

        public OutlinedFilledGlyphDrawer(Color fillColour, Color outlineColour, Stroke stroke) {
            this.fillColour = fillColour;
            this.outlineColour = outlineColour;
            this.stroke = stroke;
        }

        @Override
        public void saveGraphicsStateBeforeDraw(Graphics2D g) {
            this.oldGraphicsStateColor = g.getColor();
            this.oldGraphicsStateStroke = g.getStroke();
        }

        @Override
        public void drawGlyph(Graphics2D preTransformedG, Shape glyph) {
            preTransformedG.setColor(this.fillColour);
            preTransformedG.fill(glyph);
            preTransformedG.setColor(this.outlineColour);
            preTransformedG.setStroke(this.stroke);
            preTransformedG.draw(glyph);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreGraphicsStateAfterDraw(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setColor(this.oldGraphicsStateColor);
            g.setStroke(this.oldGraphicsStateStroke);
        }
    }
}

class TextUtilities { // Ideally separate into it's own package rather and then don't use static inner classes, but for this single-file demo, it works.
    public static enum CircularTextPosition {
        OUTSIDE_CIRCLE {
            @Override
            double calculateActualRadius(double radius, double maxAscent, double maxDescent, boolean flip) {
                return radius;
            }
        },
        BASELINE_ON_CIRCLE {
            @Override
            double calculateActualRadius(double radius, double maxAscent, double maxDescent, boolean flip) {
                return radius-(flip?maxAscent:maxDescent);
            }
        },
        INSIDE_CIRCLE {
            @Override
            double calculateActualRadius(double radius, double maxAscent, double maxDescent, boolean flip) {
                return radius-maxAscent-maxDescent;
            }
        };

        abstract double calculateActualRadius(double radius, double maxAscent, double maxDescent, boolean flip);
    }

    public static interface GlyphDrawer {
        void saveGraphicsStateBeforeDraw(Graphics2D g);
        void drawGlyph(Graphics2D preTransformedG, Shape glyph);
        void restoreGraphicsStateAfterDraw(Graphics2D g);
    }

    public static void drawTextAroundCircle(Graphics2D g, String text, int centerAngleInDegrees, boolean squash, CircularTextPosition circularTextPosition, boolean flip, double radius, double centerX, double centerY, Font font, GlyphDrawer glyphDrawer) {
        AffineTransform oldTransform = g.getTransform();
        glyphDrawer.saveGraphicsStateBeforeDraw(g);

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();

        char[] characters = text.toCharArray();
        int characterCount = characters.length;
        if (flip) {
            char[] reversedCharacters = new char[characterCount];
            for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
                reversedCharacters[index] = characters[characterCount-index-1];
            }
            characters = reversedCharacters;
        }

        double maxAscent;
        double maxDescent;
        if (squash) {
            maxAscent = 0;
            maxDescent = 0;
        } else {
            maxAscent = fm.getMaxAscent();
            maxDescent = fm.getMaxDescent();
        }

        double spaceCharacterWidth = fm.charWidth('n');
        double leading = fm.getLeading();
        boolean[] charactersAreSpaces = new boolean[characterCount];
        GlyphVector[] characterGlyphVectors = new GlyphVector[characterCount];
        Rectangle2D[] characterGlyphBounds = new Rectangle2D[characterCount];
        double[] characterWidths = new double[characterCount+1];
        double[] characterAscents = new double[characterCount];
        double[] characterDescents = new double[characterCount];
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            char character = characters[index];

            boolean isSpace = character == ' ' || Character.isSpaceChar(character);
            GlyphVector glyphVector = font.createGlyphVector(frc, Character.toString(character));
            Rectangle2D glyphBounds = glyphVector.getVisualBounds();
            double width = isSpace?spaceCharacterWidth:glyphBounds.getWidth();
            double ascent = -glyphBounds.getY();
            double descent = glyphBounds.getHeight()-ascent;

            charactersAreSpaces[index] = isSpace;
            characterGlyphVectors[index] = glyphVector;
            characterGlyphBounds[index] = glyphBounds;
            characterWidths[index] = width;
            characterAscents[index] = ascent;
            characterDescents[index] = descent;

            if (squash) {
                maxAscent = Math.max(maxAscent,ascent);
                maxDescent = Math.max(maxDescent,descent);
            }
        }

        double actualRadius = circularTextPosition.calculateActualRadius(radius, maxAscent, maxDescent, flip);

        double currentAngleInRadians = 0;
        double[] characterAnglesInRadians = new double[characterCount];
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            characterAnglesInRadians[index] = currentAngleInRadians;
            currentAngleInRadians += Math.sin(((characterWidths[index]/2.0) + leading + (characterWidths[index+1]/2.0)) / actualRadius);
        }
        double angleAdjustment = (centerAngleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180) - ((characterAnglesInRadians[characterCount-1] - characterAnglesInRadians[0]) / 2.0);
        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            characterAnglesInRadians[index] += angleAdjustment;
        }

        AffineTransform stringTransform = oldTransform;
        if (stringTransform == null) {
            stringTransform = new AffineTransform();
        }
        if (flip) {
            stringTransform.rotate(Math.PI, centerX, centerY);
        }

        for (int index=0; index<characterCount; index++) {
            if (!charactersAreSpaces[index]) {
                GlyphVector glyphVector = characterGlyphVectors[index];
                Rectangle2D glyphBounds = characterGlyphBounds[index];
                if (flip) {
                    AffineTransform oldGlyphVectorTransform = glyphVector.getGlyphTransform(0);
                    if (oldGlyphVectorTransform == null) {
                        oldGlyphVectorTransform = new AffineTransform();
                    }
                    AffineTransform newGlyphVectorTransform = new AffineTransform(oldGlyphVectorTransform);
                    newGlyphVectorTransform.scale(-1, -1);
                    newGlyphVectorTransform.translate(-(glyphBounds.getWidth()+glyphBounds.getX()+glyphBounds.getX()),glyphBounds.getHeight()+(maxAscent-characterAscents[index])-characterDescents[index]-maxDescent);
                    glyphVector.setGlyphTransform(0, newGlyphVectorTransform);
                }
                AffineTransform characterTransform = new AffineTransform(stringTransform);
                characterTransform.translate(centerX, centerY);
                characterTransform.rotate(characterAnglesInRadians[index]);
                characterTransform.translate(-((glyphBounds.getX()+(glyphBounds.getWidth()/2))),-(actualRadius+maxDescent));
                g.setTransform(characterTransform);
                glyphDrawer.drawGlyph(g, glyphVector.getOutline(0, 0));
            }
        }

        glyphDrawer.restoreGraphicsStateAfterDraw(g);
        g.setTransform(oldTransform);
    }
}
```

This can then produce *(Note that the text contains 'y' due to the large descent of that letter)*:

BASELINE_ON_CIRCLE (Not squashed):

[image: Generated image]

INSIDE_CIRCLE (Not squashed):

[image: Generated image]

OUTSIDE_CIRCLE (Not squashed):

[image: Generated image]

I hope this code is helpful to anyone else viewing this question in the future.

Comment: If I write the words containing 'I' , it messes up the angles at bottom. For example if I write "DIRECTED BY", the character 'I' goes inside 'R' and kind of disappears due to flipping logic. Is there a way to take care of that.

Comment: @RajuSingh It has been a while since I wrote this code, but I'm guessing that glyphVector.getVisualBounds() is returning a rectangle that is slightly too small for some reason, either due to a bug in my code or something else. It is a bit of a hack, but possibly add a check in there so if the character is 'I', it adds extra to the width.

Comment: This post does not get near the recognition it deserves. Great work! +1

Comment: Minor improvement: replace `double width = isSpace?spaceCharacterWidth:glyphBounds.getWidth();` with `double width = glyphVector.getGlyphMetrics(0).getAdvanceX();`. I think it will solve @Raju Singh's problem.